# Use PHP dom to check if image is inside a a-link

Tags: php, html, image, dom, anchor

I use php-dom to scrape html for images.

Now I want to check if images are image links (child of an anchor, such as `<a href=...><img src=...></a>`).

However, it might be that an img-containing anchor is not the direct parent of the image, but somewhere higher up in the DOM. Therefore, the img's ´item($node_index)->parentNode´ might not represent a declared hyperlink.

I see documentation which cycles through all anchors, and then checks if the link has an embedded image, but I'm working the other way around, as I need to resolve all images in the document. Or would it really be the most efficient to firs cycle through all img's, then through all anchors, and then to cross check?

Comment: I'm replacing possibly tracked images in an e-mail (eg https://gallery.mailchimp.com/28bc9aa0aa37525650a190eb2/images/68f888cf-a2e4-4618-8ab7-f69d8a25e19c.jpg) with embedded images.
If my server cant get the image, I want to link the image to its original, if its not already linked to somewhere else.